# Texstudio Selected Text Highlight

Tags: texstudio

When I select text in Texstudio it remains highlighted even if deselected.
The last selected section of text always has a light-blue highlighting.
This is visually very irritating and I have no idea how to get rid of it.
I might have turned it on by accident, hitting some shortcut that I am unaware of.
Does anybody know how to turn this behaviour off?

[image: Selected Text]
[image: Deselected Text]

Comment: After you deselect the selection, is your courser still in this line? (because the current line is also highlighted in light blue...)

Comment: After restarting my PC, the behaviour stopped. Though currently the highlight for the paragraph that has the cursor in it, is a much lighter shade of blue. The behaviour above also happened if I marked even just a single word.